# Action Cable - APIs Connection disconnected any time - Backend ROR, iOS, Android

Tags: android, ios, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

My backend is in **Ruby on rails,** I wrote a Taxi application where Drivers and customers subscribe to the Channels.

I have provided them my cable link: http://mydomain/cable and Channels details.

I'm using sidekiq and Redis to manage the action cable.

***Approx 40% time all works fine but in between 60% time Mobile apps start getting the following error:***

**Android**

> > onFailedcom.hosopy.actioncable.ActionCableException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
> >
> > onFailedcom.hosopy.actioncable.ActionCableException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

**iOS Apps**

> > ActionCableClient.TransmitError.notConnected

I'm using `Nginx` and `passenger` to deploy the backend **ROR** Application

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Do you use capistrano for deployment?

Comment: I had the same issue with my developer Android actually android app must keep pinging the socket to keep it open else it gets timed out.